# serialization and deserialize datetime

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

i have a class with a property datetime such as

```
class myclass {
    DateTime date{get;set;} 
}
```

the content is

01/09/2015 00:00:00

i convert the class with

```
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(myclassInstance);
```

and when i deserialize the date is 31/08/2015 22:00:00
the deserialization is made with

```
myclass mc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myclass>(json) as myclass ;
```

how can i preserve the format date?

Comment: What is the `Kind` of the original `DateTime` value? That's almost certainly the issue. (`DateTime` is unfortunately broken in a number of ways, and there's no simple way for JSON serialization to account for that.)

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't it meant as a simple type to just hold data? having anything else would make it really hard to use, just like java, imo

Comment: One workaround is to convert the date to a string and then serialize / deserialize that. You can get the original DateTime object back by calling DateTime.Parse(string)

Comment: @auburg for me I normally create a SerializableDate or something like that, that has a Getter and Setter that sets the Date, and I put a JsonIgnore at the date. Would be good solution for OP.

Comment: @Mafii: Well I think it's broken, which is why I created [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org). See http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Comment: @JonSkeet oh, I like that one, its really clean. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Use your DateTime values in UTC. That way you can also be sure that the date/time used on the one end of the wire (in, say, North America) is the same as that received on the other side (in, say, Europe).